# Find if string contains one of the word in list and print the word it finds

Tags: python

I want to find if one word in list exists in a string and then print the found value. I am able to do this, but only with a true/false output.

```
mylist = ['IP', 'PR1','PR2']
str=('S:\QUAREP\Controlli\12011191\2022-06-29\STL\12011191-92-95-202-203_220701_PR1.g3d')
x = any(mylist)
print (x)
```

With the print (x) I print, in this case, true. But I want to print 'PR1'. Alternatively for me is useful the index, too. How to do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
mylist = ['IP', 'PR1','PR2']
string = 'S:\QUAREP\Controlli\12011191\2022-06-29\STL\12011191-92-95-202-203_220701_PR1.g3d'

print([ele for ele in mylist if(ele in string)])
```

Comment: And since `if` is not a function you can drop the unneeded parentheses: `print([ele for ele in mylist if ele in string])`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have to use this to split the string, but it returns the error "must be str or None, not list". This is the code:                                            `causali = ['IP', 'TP', 'PR1', 'PR2', 'PR3', 'TP', 'BC', 'BF', 'VP', 'RP']
file = (gom.app.project.parts[0].actual.import_information.name)
print (file)
causale=([ele for ele in causali if ele in file])
print (causale)
ls=file.split(causale)
print (ls)`